# fail2ban repeatedly sends notifications

Tags: security, nginx, notifications, fail2ban

we re facing issue with fail2ban.

Our setup for example:

jail.conf:

```
[nginx-404]

enabled = true
port    = http,https
filter  = nginx-404
logpath = /var/log/nginx/*access.log
maxretry = 5
findtime = 300
action = mail
```

than action:

```
[Definition]

actionstart =
actionstop =
actioncheck =

actionban = printf %%b "Hi,\n
            The IP <ip> has just been banned by Fail2Ban after
            <failures> attempts against <name>.\n
            Regards,\n
            Fail2Ban"|mail -s "[Fail2Ban] <name>: banned <ip> from `uname -n`" <dest>

actionunban =
```

After restart service or reboot system. It send immediately all bans which were done before.

Is there any solution to stop sending hundreds notifications after restart ? Thanks for anyadvice.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any solution to stop sending hundreds notifications after restart ?

Yes. Just specify `norestored = true` in your action. See [PR #1669](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/pull/1669) for more info.